# Pythond 3d surface plot with holes

Tags: python, plot, graph, 3d

i´m pretty new in Python and have a Problem i´m not understanding: Im Creating an 3D plot of data which contains the time, x-axis and strain of a test specimen. But in the plot are big holes which look pretty bad... can anyone help me?

thank in advance!

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

df_N1 = pd.read_csv(f".....", sep=',',
                # index_col='Zeit',
                # skiprows= 1,
                # header = None,
                decimal='.',
                encoding='unicode_escape',
                float_precision='high')


df_NX = pd.read_csv(f"....", sep=',',
                index_col=0,
                # skiprows= 1,
                header = None,
                decimal='.',
                encoding='unicode_escape',
                float_precision='high')

X = np.array(df_N1.iloc[1:,0])
Y = np.array(df_NX.iloc[0,0:])
Z = np.array(df_N1.iloc[1:,1:])
Z=Z.transpose()


X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X,
                       Y,
                       Z,
                       vmin=np.amin(Z),
                       vmax=np.amax(Z),
                       linewidth=10,
                       antialiased=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMF09.png)

I want the holes to be close. so i can get a "smooth" surface :)

Comment: does your `Z` variable contain any NaN values?